# Elastic Search query against nested and non nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing restaurant and their dishes in ES. The restaurant dishes are nested and a list of several dishes. The restaurant name and cuisines (a list too) comes outside. The structure is somewhat like this:

```
{ 
     "restaurant_name": "Dominos",
     "cuisines": ["Italian", "Continental"],
     "restaurant_dishes": [
          {
              "dish_name": "Margherita"
          },
          {
               "dish_name": "Piri Piri Pizza"
          }
      ]
}
```

I am trying to run a should (OR) query against them like this:

```
{
  "query": {

    "bool": { 
              "should": [ 
                          {
                              "term": {"restaurant_name": "Dominos"}
                          },
                          {    
                              "nested": {

                                "path": "restaurant_dishes",
                                "query": {
                                          "match": {
                                            "dish_name": "Dominos"
                                                   }
                                          }
                                       }
                          }
                        ],
             "minimum_number_should_match": 1

    }

  }
}
```

Here is the mapping:

```
  {
        "restaurant": {
            "_routing": {
                "required": True,
                "path": "id"
            },
        "properties": {
              "restaurant_name": {"type": "string", "index":"analyzed", "analyzer": "standard"},},
        "restaurant_dishes": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {"dish_name": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "standard"},}
```

I expect this to return the listing because `"name"` field matches. However it returns an empty list. I basically want to implement a single search box which searches for `restaurant name, cuisines and dish names` in a single query.

Comment: shouldn't it be *restaurant_name* instead of *name* i.e  *"term": {"restaurant_name": "Dominos"}*

Comment: It is. I wrote the above instead of copy-pasting. Will edit it here.

Comment: cool ,can you paste the mapping too

Comment: Just added the mapping. Please note that I am omitting the other fields for sake of brevity.

Comment: Search for "dominos" instead of "Dominos" for your `term` query.

Comment: `term` doesn't analyze the input text, so it's searching for exactly "Dominos" (capital letter) whereas you are indexing the text using the `standard` analyzer which, among others, will lowercase the terms.